# AM working on a site using django framework and i got this AttributeError

Tags: python, django

This is the AttributeError error message I get:

```
AttributeError at /polls/
'str' object has no attribute 'get'
Request Method:     GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/polls/
Django Version:     2.0.2
Exception Type:     AttributeError
Exception Value: ``'str' object has no attribute 'get'
Exception Location:     C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django-2.0.2-py3.4.egg\django\middleware\clickjacking.py in process_response, line 26
Python Executable:  C:\Python34\python.exe
Python Version:     3.4.1
Python Path: ['C:\\Users\\WUESE PHILIP\\Desktop\\vibezt',
'C:\\Python34\\python34.zip',
'C:\\Python34\\DLLs',
'C:\\Python34\\lib',
'C:\\Python34',
'C:\\Python34\\lib\\site-packages',
'C:\\Python34\\lib\\site-packages\\setuptools-33.1.1-py3.4.egg',
'C:\\Python34\\lib\\site-packages\\django-2.0.2-py3.4.egg',
'C:\\Python34\\lib\\site-packages\\pytz-2019.3-py3.4.egg']
```

---

These are my Django files:

polls urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views
urlpatterns = [
path('', views.index, name='index'),
]
```

---

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
def index(request):
    return("<h2>Welcome to my First Python Django Project</h2>")
```

---

vibezt urls.py­­­­­­­­­

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import include, path
urlpatterns = [
    path('polls/', include('polls.urls')),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),]
```

............................................

Comment: Please reformat your message to make it clear. You are not correctly using code section and you are not explaining clearly your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to check the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/intro/tutorial03/#writing-more-views) and return a Response from your view.